# renaming a SQL Server with installed named instances

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a hosted server that is named, by the hosting company, as something like WinEnt99. We would like to rename it to something more meaning like OurMonitor1.

We have already installed a few instances of SQL Server 2008 R2.

Is there anything that we need to (re)configure in SQL Server / SSMS ?

I have an application that was reading the database settings from the registry, and connecting the database fine. Now, it won't connect to the database. The only thing that I can think of is that we renamed the server last week sometime.

EDIT 02 Oct 2012:-
The Server is being renamed. The named instances are not.

I've run

```
sp_helpserver
select @@servername
```

Which showed the old server name,
and

```
sp_dropserver 'Old Server Name\Instance_name'
go
sp_addserver 'New Server Name\Instance Name','local'
go
```

Then confirmed the details in

```
sp_helpserver
select @@servername
```

Comment: I've just noticed one of my questions from a few months ago was migrated to Database Administrators. I suspect this one would suit better there.

Comment: While this is probably better suited for DBA.SE. You should not cross-post questions on different sites. This was cross-posted on DBA.SE http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25214/renaming-a-sql-server-with-installed-named-instances

Answer (score 10):

First collect the output of the current instance configuration. You can get the instance name stored in the SQL Server metadata.

Make sure you have backup of all the database if you are changing the production server instance name.

```
sp_helpserver
select @@servername
```

You can change the instance name using below query.
Default Instance

```
sp_dropserver 'old_name'
go
sp_addserver 'new_name','local'
go
```

<strike>Named Instance</strike>

```
sp_dropserver 'Server Name\old_Instance_name'
go
sp_addserver 'ServerName\New Instance Name','local'
go
```

Verify sql server instance configuration by running below queries

```
sp_helpserver
select @@servername
```

Restart the SQL Server Services.

```
net stop MSSQLServer
net start MSSQLServer
```

[Update]

You cannot change connection instance name as this action is not supported. Only option is re-install SQL server.
[See answer in MSDN here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/d5d297b0-2995-46ba-9d3b-d1ec8825f479)

Answer (score 1):

There is no command to rename an instance. You will need to create a new instance side by side, move the databases by whichever method you'd like (backup & restore would be fine) and drop the previous instance.

```
sp_addserver "OurMonitor1" , local

sp_dropserver "WinEnt99"
```